# Check for location crashes Android App

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, location

I'm writing my app to check if the location is turned on in the app. I have the below check. When the location isn't turned on, inside the `getLocation()` method, I have an AlertDialog that gets built to alert the user that they must turn on their location, but instead of displaying the alert, the app crashes with a `nullpointer` exception because I try to access the size of the arrayList `getLocation()` returns.

This is my call to the line that crashes it.

```
latLongValues = getLocation();
Log.d("LATLONG VALUES", latLongValues.size() + "");
```

Here is my `getLocation` function

```
private ArrayList<Double> getLocation() {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if(isLocationEnabled(locationManager)){
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            ArrayList<Double> values = new ArrayList<>();

            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();

            values.add(latitude);
            values.add(longitude);

            return values;
        }
        else if(!isLocationEnabled(locationManager)){
            Log.d("LOCATION IS NOT ENABLED", "locatoin not enabled");
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Turn on location and click \"OK")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            getLocation();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }

        return null;
    }

private boolean isLocationEnabled(LocationManager lm){
        boolean gps = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        boolean network = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if(!gps && !network){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because only if the location is enabled, you declared:

```
ArrayList<Double> values = new ArrayList<>();
```

What about the second case?

That's why your ArrayList is null when the location is disabled.

Initialize it before the `if`

And don't return null in the end of the function.
you should `return values;`